# How to use ByteArray.getOrElse

Tags: kotlin

I don't undertand how to specify the default value for `ByteArray.getOrElse() function.

I tried:

```
myInt = dat.getOrElse(0, 0).toInt()
```

but compiler complains with the following error:

```
The integer literal does not conform to the expected type (Int) -> Byte
```

How to specify the default value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expected type of the second argument (`defaultValue`) is `(Int) -> Byte` which is a lambda that takes an `Int` and returns a `Byte`.

```
myInt = dat.getOrElse(index = 100, defaultValue = { 
    i -> 
    // use i to calcuate your Byte that should be returned...
    // or return a fixed value
    i * 1 // for example
})
```

Signature of [`getOrElse`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/get-or-else.html):

```
fun ByteArray.getOrElse(
    index: Int, 
    defaultValue: (Int) -> Byte
): Byte
```

Answer (score 0):

The second argument is a function literal

```
myInt = dat.getOrElse(100, { /** what is there is no element 100*/ 0 })
```